# moving specific field value to another table before deleting the whole row

Tags: mysql, codeigniter, activerecord

I have a table with 7 fields, when I delete a row from the table by id i want two fields of that row to be inserted into another table with just two columns.

This is my controller function

```
public function refund() {

        $id = $this->uri->segment(4);

        $accounts = $this->accounts_model->get_accounts_data_by_id($id);

        foreach ($accounts as $row) {

            $data = array(
                'barcode' => $row->barcode,
                'refunded_amount' => $row->refunded_amount,
            );
        }
        $this->accounts_model->insert_refund($data);
        $this->accounts_model->delete_accounts_data($id);
    }
```

these are model functions

```
public function delete_accounts_data($id) {
        $this->db->where('id', $id);
        $this->db->delete('accounts');
    }
    public function insert_refund($data){
        $this->db->insert('refund', $data);
    }
```

Suppose this the row i will delete

```
id|name|barcode|refunded_amount|commission

01|asd |2342342|        53.01  | 5.32
```

on the other hand i will insert as

```
id|barcode|refunded_amount

01|2342342|     53.01
```

Comment: Please describe your problem...

Comment: I have a table with 7 fields, when I delete a row from the table by id i want two fields of that row to be inserted into another table with just two columns.

Comment: This looks OK to me. Are you getting any errors? Is the row being inserted? Or, deleted?

Comment: That's the problem, no error or warning but no insertion or deletion

Answer (score 0):

You should try and debug your code for general errors, e.g,
1) Try to set the environment to `development` in `index.php`.
2) Add some `debugging code` in your function to check for errors.

```
function refund(){
    $id = $this->uri->segment(4);
    $accounts = $this->accounts_model->get_accounts_data_by_id($id);
    echo $this->db->last_query(); //will produce the query for fetching the details by id
    if( isset( $accounts ) && count( $accounts ) > 0 ){
        foreach ($accounts as $row) {
            $data = array(
                'barcode' => $row->barcode,
                'refunded_amount' => $row->refunded_amount,
            );
        }
        print_r( $data );
        $this->accounts_model->insert_refund($data);
        $this->accounts_model->delete_accounts_data($id);
    }else{
        echo "NO DATA FOUND";
    }
}
```

Comment: I have tried your way. No luck. Is it okay to write like $accounts = $this->accounts_model->get_accounts_data_by_id($id); and send it through a loop? Is there any issue about those model function?

Comment: can you post your function `get_accounts_data_by_id`